# How to replace all new lines, tabs, and excess whitespace in a text file

Tags: python, text, replace

I have a text file of a book and I want it read into my python program to split it into sentences by using `open("book.txt").read().split(".")`.

The problem is the file has new line breaks and multiple spaces. I want the file to be only the words separated by a space and all new lines turned into just a single space.

My `book.txt` is currently like this (a snippet):

```
To Sherlock Holmes she is always the woman. I have seldom
heard him mention her under any other name. In his eyes she
eclipses and predominates the whole of her sex. It was not that
he felt any emotion akin to love for Irene Adler. All emotions,
and that one particularly, were abhorrent to his cold, precise but
admirably balanced mind. He was, I take it, the most perfect
reasoning and observing machine that the world has seen, but as
a lover he would have placed himself in a false position. He
never spoke of the softer passions, save with a gibe and a sneer.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into Python's various string methods?

Comment: What happens when a sentence ends in a question mark, like often questions do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to remove all line breaks and trailing white space...

maybe something like...

```
import re
sentences = [re.sub("^\s*|\s*$,"",re.sub("\n","",each))  for each in open("book.txt").read().split(".")]
```

or if tabs are also a problem...

```
sentences = [re.sub("^\s*|\s*$","",re.sub("\s+"," ",each))  for each in open("book.txt").read().split(".")]
```

to also split by ?,!, or . use...

```
sentences = [re.sub("^\s*|\s*$","",re.sub("\s+"," ",each))  for each in re.split("[\?\.!]",open("book.txt").read())]
```

Comment: What if I want to split by question marks period as well as exclamation points? How will I modify this?

Comment: Instead of using the split method use re.split(pattern,string).  To include periods,Exclamations and question marks check out my edit

Comment: The quotes are off in this example. Is it supposed to be like this because the for loop is in a string. How do you fix this?

Comment: I just fixed the quotes should be fine now